# combine one column from one table with other column from two other tables sql

Tags: sql, join, union

i'm not entirely sure how to title my question, if someone knows a better title, please feel free to edit it.

Basically I have a problem and I'm not sure what to do.

I have a database with Delivery Address, and Billing address. If Delivery address is null, I want it to display billing address. I have achieved this using:

```
SELECT DELIVERYADDRESS AS "Address"
FROM SHOPORDER so
UNION 
SELECT BILLINGADDR AS "Address"
FROM CUSTOMER
```

So that works. I also need it to be 'connected' to its order. So i do this:

```
SELECT ORDID FROM SHOPORDER
```

What i want is my table to look like
|ORDID | ADDRESS (DeliveryAddress or BillingAddress if DeliveryAddress null)


Note that my question sheet states that i must use a union. I tried this:

```
SELECT ORDID, (SELECT DELIVERYADDRESS FROM SHOPORDER
    UNION 
        SELECT BILLINGADDR FROM CUSTOMER)
FROM SHOPORDER
```

But it doesn't work. I've been trying this for an hour, and I just can't figure it out. I've tried inner joins, left joins, right joins, etc. I just can't figure it out. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use coalesce for this:

select ordid, coalesce(deliveryaddress, billingaddress) from
shoporder join customer using (customerid)

assuming that customerid is the field that joins the two tables.
Coalesce is very simple: if the first parameter is null, it uses the second.

--dmg

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned UNION is compulsory

```
SELECT ORDID,DELIVERYADDRESS AS "Address"
FROM SHOPORDER 
WHERE DELIVERYADDRESS IS NOT NULL

UNION 

SELECT ORDID,BILLINGADDR AS "Address"
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE ORDID IN ( SELECT ORDID
                 FROM SHOPORDER 
                 DELIVERYADDRESS IS NULL
               )
```

Comment: I don't think the Customer table would have the column ORDERID

Comment: yeah, customer doesn't have ORDID, which is why I'm having such a problem with this :/

Comment: @nhasan thanks to your solution i was able to come up with a solution, i'll mark yours as best answer but i'll also post mine just incase anyone else has a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CustomerId,
SHOPORDER.ORDERID,
COALESCE(SHOPORDER.DELIVERYADDRESS, CUSTOMER.BILLINGADDR) AS "Address",
CASE SHOPORDER.DELIVERYADDRESS IS NOT NULL THEN 'D' ELSE 'B' END AS AddressType,
FROM CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN SHOPORDER
ON CUSTOMER.CustomerId = SHOPORDER.CustomerId
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working, by looking at mhasan's answer:

```
SELECT ORDID,DELIVERYADDRESS AS "Address"
FROM SHOPORDER so
WHERE DELIVERYADDRESS IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT so.ORDID, c.BILLINGADDR AS "Address"
FROM SHOPORDER so
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER c
ON so.CUSTID = c.CUSTID
WHERE so.DELIVERYADDRESS IS NULL
ORDER BY ORDID ASC
```

Comment: I am curious, why don't you use coalesce? It will be done in a simpler statement (the second join you have in the UNION) and it will be more efficient.

Comment: I'll end your curiosity dmg. This is for assignment I guess!